# Azure V2 timer function don't work with httpclient progress when redirected by 302 response

Tags: azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to `HTTP GET` a file and added a progress handler to see the progress since the file is rather large, but I cannot get this to work, it seems to be no trigger when bytes are downloaded.

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE, this is an `Azure V2 Timer Function`

```
namespace NWPimDataFeeder
{
   public static class PimDataFeeder
  {
    [FunctionName("PimDataFeeder")]
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    var processMsgHander = new ProgressMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler());
    processMsgHander.HttpSendProgress += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //add your codes base on e.BytesTransferred and e.ProgressPercentage
    };

     processMsgHander.HttpReceiveProgress += (sender, e) =>
    {
        log.Info(e.BytesTransferred.ToString());
    };

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(processMsgHander))
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function in the using executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        HttpResponseMessage file = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com/api/blaha");
        var JsonLineFile = await file.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        log.Info(JsonLineFile);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

--- EDIT ---
THe code works fine if the file available at the original location, but my response is a 302 redirect and for some reason it is not followed so my variable contains the HTML content of the redirect HTML page as oppose to the destination content after the redirect, how can I fix that?

Comment: is it working in a console app ?

Comment: Have not tried a console app

Comment: the code seems to work fine for me, at least locally. Are you debugging locally or trying to see the progress in the portal?

Comment: debugging locally I see no progress at all

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is that the response is a 302 redirect and I capturing that redirect HTML and not the content AFTER the redirect so to say, not really sure how to do that, I assumed that httpclient would follow the redirects automatically

Comment: I guess you can easily confirm this by using a different JSON file. This one is working for me:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corysimmons/colors.json/master/colors.json

Comment: Yes that works fine for me too, so definitely something with redirect

Comment: 302 redirects should work though as long as they dont redirect from https to http

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181784/discussion-between-thomas-and-matt-douhan).